# Pick value by swiping image on horizontal bar

Tags: android

[image]

I want below mentioned functionality in my app but don't know which widget i should use.

As like above image, user can slide image/view on horizontal bar to pick value, user can pick any value between 0 and 720, There is milestone at every 30 points

Now the main point is as soon as user swipe image to right most on horizontal line, Line must scroll towards left and must change milestones accordingly (Like 90,120,150.....720) so basically its horizontal value picker and user can slide it to pick desired number.

Also user can swipe right to left to select previous values. values are fixed 0 to 720

Comment: Lya.. Panchal aani repo banavine Github par muki de

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!  https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar

and try to change the thumb to drawable

```
Drawable myThumb = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slider_button);
myThumb.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, myThumb.getIntrinsicWidth(),myThumb.getIntrinsicHeight()));
skbr.setThumb(myThumb);
```

[How can I change the Android SeekBar Thumb drawable after 'onCreate' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882992/how-can-i-change-the-android-seekbar-thumb-drawable-after-oncreate-method)

Comment: Thanks for you help @Ashrith, but this is not what i want, as you can see my seekbar is not fixed it will scroll when user goes to right side and will show new values